# How can I use netbeans to export each package into separate jars?

Tags: netbeans, jar, java

Right now, netbeans exports all the packages in a single project into a single jar, I would like it to export a separate jar for each package, how would I go about doing that?

Would also like to know how can I include all my dependent libraries into the generated jar

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to?

Comment: so that I can simply have a single portable neat package for the user